# Find concatenated words among list of words

Tags: javascript, algorithm, concatenation

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [472. Concatenated Words](https://leetcode.com/problems/concatenated-words/description/):

> Given an array of strings `words` (**without duplicates**), return *all the **concatenated words** in the given list of* `words`.
>
> A **concatenated word** is defined as a string that is comprised entirely of at least two shorter words (not necesssarily distinct) in the given array.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> - **Input:** `words = ["cat","cats","catsdogcats","dog","dogcatsdog","hippopotamuses","rat","ratcatdogcat"]`
> - **Output:** `["catsdogcats","dogcatsdog","ratcatdogcat"]`
> - **Explanation:** "catsdogcats" can be concatenated by "cats", "dog" and "cats";
>   "dogcatsdog" can be concatenated by "dog", "cats" and "dog";
>   "ratcatdogcat" can be concatenated by "rat", "cat", "dog" and "cat".

#### My attempt

I approached the problem by implementing a trie and performing a depth-first search. Here is the code:

```js
var findAllConcatenatedWordsInADict = function(ws) {
    const arr = [];

    class Trie {
        constructor() {
            this.root = new TrieNode();
        }

        create(w) {
            let node = this.root;
            for(let i=0; i<w.length; ++i) {
                const c = w[i];
                node.next[c] = node.next[c] || new TrieNode();
                node = node.next[c];
            } // end loop

            node.end = true;
            node.word = w;
        }
 
        find(w, ind, depth) {
            let node = this.root;
            for(let i=ind; i<w.length; ++i) {
                const c = w[i];
                if(node.next[c] === undefined) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    node = node.next[c];
                }

                if(node.end === true) {
                    if(i === w.length-1) {
                        if(depth >= 1) {
                            arr.push(w);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    if(this.find(w, i+1, depth+1)) { 
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } // end loop

            return false;
        }
    }

    class TrieNode {
        constructor() {
            this.next = {};
            this.end = false;
            this.word = '';
        }
    }

    const trie = new Trie();
    for(let i=0; i<ws.length; ++i) {
        const w = ws[i];
        trie.create(w);
    } // end loop

    for(let i=0; i<ws.length; ++i) {
        const w = ws[i];
        trie.find(w, 0, 0);
    } // end loop

    return arr;
};
```

#### Problem

For large inputs, the algorithm is taking too much time, and LeetCode gives a "time limit exceeded" error.

Here is an example of an input for which the function exceeds the time limit:

```
["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz","b","bb","bbb","bbbb","bbbbb","bbbbbb","bbbbbbb","bbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbz","c","cc","ccc","cccc","ccccc","cccccc","ccccccc","cccccccc","ccccccccc","cccccccccc","ccccccccccc","cccccccccccc","ccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccc","ccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccc","ccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccc","ccccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccccc","ccccccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccccccc","ccccccccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccccccccc","ccccccccccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccccccccccc","ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc","ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccz","d","dd","ddd","dddd","ddddd","dddddd","ddddddd","dddddddd","ddddddddd","dddddddddd","ddddddddddd","dddddddddddd","ddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddd","ddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddd","ddddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddddd","ddddddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddddddd","ddddddddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddddddddd","ddddddddddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddddddddddd","ddddddddddddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddddddddddddd","ddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddz","e","ee","eee","eeee","eeeee","eeeeee","eeeeeee","eeeeeeee","eeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeez","f","ff","fff","ffff","fffff","ffffff","fffffff","ffffffff","fffffffff","ffffffffff","fffffffffff","ffffffffffff","fffffffffffff","ffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffff","ffffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffffff","ffffffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffffffff","ffffffffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffffffffff","ffffffffffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffffffffffff","ffffffffffffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffffffffffffff","ffffffffffffffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffffffffffffffff","ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff","ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff","fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffz","g","gg","ggg","gggg","ggggg","gggggg","ggggggg","gggggggg","ggggggggg","gggggggggg","ggggggggggg","gggggggggggg","ggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggg","ggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggg","ggggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggggg","ggggggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggggggg","ggggggggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggggggggg","ggggggggggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggggggggggg","ggggggggggggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggggggggggggg","ggggggggggggggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggggggggggggggg","ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg","gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggz","h","hh","hhh","hhhh","hhhhh","hhhhhh","hhhhhhh","hhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh","hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhz","i","ii","iii","iiii","iiiii","iiiiii","iiiiiii","iiiiiiii","iiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiz","j","jj","jjj","jjjj","jjjjj","jjjjjj","jjjjjjj","jjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjz","k","kk","kkk","kkkk","kkkkk","kkkkkk","kkkkkkk","kkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkz","l","ll","lll","llll","lllll","llllll","lllllll","llllllll","lllllllll","llllllllll","lllllllllll","llllllllllll","lllllllllllll","llllllllllllll","lllllllllllllll","llllllllllllllll","lllllllllllllllll","llllllllllllllllll","lllllllllllllllllll","llllllllllllllllllll","lllllllllllllllllllll","llllllllllllllllllllll","lllllllllllllllllllllll","llllllllllllllllllllllll","lllllllllllllllllllllllll","llllllllllllllllllllllllll","lllllllllllllllllllllllllll","llllllllllllllllllllllllllll","lllllllllllllllllllllllllllll","llllllllllllllllllllllllllllll","lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllz","m","mm","mmm","mmmm","mmmmm","mmmmmm","mmmmmmm","mmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmz","n","nn","nnn","nnnn","nnnnn","nnnnnn","nnnnnnn","nnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn","nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnz","o","oo","ooo","oooo","ooooo","oooooo","ooooooo","oooooooo","ooooooooo","oooooooooo","ooooooooooo","oooooooooooo","ooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooo","ooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooo","ooooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooooo","ooooooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooooooo","ooooooooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooooooooo","ooooooooooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooooooooooo","ooooooooooooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooooooooooooo","ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooooooooooooooo","ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo","oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooz","p","pp","ppp","pppp","ppppp","pppppp","ppppppp","pppppppp","ppppppppp","pppppppppp","ppppppppppp","pppppppppppp","ppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppp","ppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppp","ppppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppppp","ppppppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppppppp","ppppppppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppppppppp","ppppppppppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppppppppppp","ppppppppppppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppppppppppppp","ppppppppppppppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppppppppppppppp","ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp","pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppz","q","qq","qqq","qqqq","qqqqq","qqqqqq","qqqqqqq","qqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqz","r","rr","rrr","rrrr","rrrrr","rrrrrr","rrrrrrr","rrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr","rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrz","s","ss","sss","ssss","sssss","ssssss","sssssss","ssssssss","sssssssss","ssssssssss","sssssssssss","ssssssssssss","sssssssssssss","ssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssss","ssssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssssss","ssssssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssssssss","ssssssssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssssssssss","ssssssssssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssssssssssss","ssssssssssssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssssssssssssss","ssssssssssssssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssssssssssssssss","ssssssssssssssssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssssssssssssssssss","ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssz","t","tt","ttt","tttt","ttttt","tttttt","ttttttt","tttttttt","ttttttttt","tttttttttt","ttttttttttt","tttttttttttt","ttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttt","ttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttt","ttttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttttt","ttttttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttttttt","ttttttttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttttttttt","ttttttttttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttttttttttt","ttttttttttttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttttttttttttt","ttttttttttttttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttttttttttttttt","ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt","tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttz","u","uu","uuu","uuuu","uuuuu","uuuuuu","uuuuuuu","uuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu","uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuz","v","vv","vvv","vvvv","vvvvv","vvvvvv","vvvvvvv","vvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvz","w","ww","www","wwww","wwwww","wwwwww","wwwwwww","wwwwwwww","wwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwz","x","xx","xxx","xxxx","xxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxz","y","yy","yyy","yyyy","yyyyy","yyyyyy","yyyyyyy","yyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"]
```

Particular about this input are the many occurrences of strings that are just repetitions of one-letter words, like "a", with different lengths, which would all be found as eligible for inclusion in the output. The input also includes variants that also start out with such repeated characters, but which are followed by a different letter suffix, to disqualify them for inclusion in the output. My code will produce the expected output, but it just takes too long.

I expected a trie to be an efficient approach. Am I missing some possibilities to store/find the data more efficiently in the trie?

Comment: Please provide the context for this question.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Also provide sample input, expected output, actual output and why actual differs from expected if not obvious.

Comment: As there was no reaction I took the liberty to do quite an overhaul of your question, addressing the point of the missing context, and problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the solution by **not** storing strings in the trie when they can be constructed from smaller words that are already in the trie. Currently you also add those, but they make the trie unnecessary "heavy", leading to searches that are not necessary.

To make this shortcut possible, you should add words to the trie in order of their lengths. That way you are sure that potential partitions of the current string are already in the trie. In short, you could combine the functions `create` and `find` so that if you have "found" a string to have constructing partitions in the trie, you don't call `create`.

Here is the update of your code that implements that idea:

```
var findAllConcatenatedWordsInADict = function(words) {
    const arr = [];

    class Trie {
        constructor() {
            this.root = new TrieNode();
        }

        create(w, node=null) {
            node ??= this.root;
            for (const c of w) {
                node = node.next[c] ??= new TrieNode();
            }
            node.end = true;
        }
 
        findOrCreate(word, ind=0) {
            let node = this.root;
            for (let i = ind; i < word.length; ++i) {
                const c = word[i];
                if (!node.next[c]) {
                    if (!ind) {
                        this.create(word.slice(i), node);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                node = node.next[c];

                if (node.end) {
                    if (i === word.length - 1) {
                        return ind > 0;
                    }
                    if (this.findOrCreate(word, i + 1)) { 
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    class TrieNode {
        constructor() {
            this.next = {};
            this.end = false;
        }
    }

    let byLength = Array.from({length: 31}, () => []);
    for (const word of words) byLength[word.length].push(word);

    const trie = new Trie();
    return byLength.flat().filter(word => trie.findOrCreate(word));
};
```

Comment: Any feedback to this answer, @kenpeter?